# Atom Editor to Change Encoding to UTF-8

Tags: encoding, utf-8, atom-editor

Good evening all ~

Someone sent me a simple SQL text file to integrate into an application that requires UTF-8 encoding.  I'm on a Mac, they are on windows, but I don't know what encoding they used.

Doing a `file -I` on the sql file returns:
`application/octet-stream; charset=binary`

When I open in Atom editor on MacOS, I can read the file with UTF-8, as selected in the lower right subbar (between the line break = LF, and syntax = SQL) but I can tell it's not really saved as UTF8, for two reasons:

1. the `/* SQL comments */` do not trigger the SQL Syntax coloring using UTF8,
   i.e., the syntax editor to not recognize the `/* comment text */` as comments,
   i assume because of the extra non-visible character is messing up the pattern match. when I switch to
   UTF-16LE, the `/* comment text */` snaps to the right dark-grey as expected,
   i.e., the editor is now reading the text appropriately
2. when i left/right arrow around the file, it takes 2 arrows to
   traverse one character. likewise, the row/column counter in the
   lower left (after the filepath) ticks off two column count for
   every single visible character the cursor moves

I'm assuming the encoding selector in the lower right is for viewing only, which makes sense.   Given this is a simple SQL file with no special characters, I really want to "Save As UTF8" and have the editor throw away the extra non-visible characters.

I've tried a number of solutions i've found online, all with no luck:

- cut all contents from original file, change encoding to UTF8, then
  paste and save... no behavior change
- create new UTF8 file, then copy/paste in all contents... interestingly
  I end up with a "UTF8" file that requires 4 left-arrows per visible
  character shift.  Wrong direction.
- run `iconv -c -t UTF-8 Dictionary_Analysis.coa.sql > DictTest.sql`
  no behavior change
- changed file to UTF8 and manually re-typed some of the comments...
  this worked! for those bytes i manually entered, they are UTF8, as
  behaviors 1 and 2 return to 'normal', as in 1 left-arrow == 1 column
  count == one visible movement, and comments are syntax-colored correctly.

But i don't want to retype their entire SQL document.  Call me lazy, but i'm sure there's a better way.

Thoughts?

Two additional thoughts... i'll likely continue to get SQL files in the future with this problem, so ideally this is something i can script or build a short .py file to account for.   Second, Atom is an awesome editor, so it surprises me i'm having so much trouble with this seemingly simple task.  I feel like i'm missing something obvious, either about the encoding or about Atom Editor...  education is always appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: **update**  i figured out a WORK-AROUND:  Find/Replace the hidden /non-printable characters with nothing.  I tried this before without luck - but I normally leave my Atom find/replace set to "regex".  On a whim I flipped back to straight find/replace, shift-left arrow to 'select'  one of the hidden characters, and replaced with nothing.   Done!    Still not really a solution...  don't know what those characters are nor the real root-cause, but at least i have a work-around for now.